# When is a normal curve sure to "fit" to a histogram of probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In order to be able to create a histogram for the probabilities of an event (e.g. scoring 0,1,2,3...n heads in a row) that matches a normal curve the distribution must be symmetric.

Something like:
[image]

My question is: is there in general a relation between how big the n is with whether we can have a histogram such as the one in the image or is it irrelevant?
What would it depend on then?

**Update after the comments:**
Yes my example with the coin is indeed a binomial distribution but it was only an example of a case that can be represented by a histogram.
My question was about the cases that the histogram matches a normal curve.

Comment: Sounds like you want to know about the Central Limit Theorem of a Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: What? Why must a histogram be symmetric? Yes—in order to fit a normal curve to a histogram it needs to be symmetrical—but the body reads "in order to be able to create a histogram for the probabilities of an event (...) the distribution must be symmetric". Where does this claim come from?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29: You are right. I corrected the post

Comment: @Sean: You could have included a link... [Central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)

Comment: A "head/tail" random variable doesn't follow a normal curve but a binomial one. It is symmetrical for a fair coin.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong (or I don't understand it). What do you mean by "be able to create" ?

Comment: "a histogram such as the one in the image": in what way the same ? Are you talking of the theoretical histogram of a discrete distribution, or the histogram of drawn samples (i.e. a random variable) ?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29: The approximating normal distribution is, of course, normal. However, the normal approximation works for large enough $n$ even if $p \ne 1/2,$ as shown in my Answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The "histogram" in the Question may actually be a bar chart of a binomial PDF. Or it could result from a large-scale simulation yielding many values of a binomial with something like $n=16$ and $p=1/2.$ I took the awkward first sentence to be a translation error rather than a mistake, but it could use clarification.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:I edited the post to clarify. Does it help?

Comment: @Jim: no, it obscures it a lot. Now I have no more idea what you are asking. Did you read any of the answers ?

Comment: You put the word "fit" in quotes, creating substantial doubt about what you might mean.  One clue is that you ask about the number of groups shown in the histogram, but this is not really a helpful clue.  A normal distribution has two degrees of freedom/parmeters, i.e. the mean and variance, which we can easily visualize as the location of the peak and the narrowness or breadth of the peak in the normal curve.  A third parameter for sample size (because the normal distribution is not size dependent) is available.

Comment: @hardmath: By "fit" I mean that the area covered by the curve is the same as the what is covered by the histogram

Comment: @Jim:  I don't think you've stated the meaning as precisely as we could wish.  The "area covered by the curve" equaling "what is covered by the historgram" is only one equation, satisfied by the area under both being normalized to probability one.  Possibly you have in mind a condition that is met for *each bar* of the histogram, though whether a exact or an approximate equality is unclear, as is the disposition of areas under the curve not corresponding to any of the finitely many(?) bars of the histogram ("tails" of the normal curve), and whether all bars of the histogram have equal widths.

Comment: @hardmath: Each bar's height equals the probability of getting x heads where x is in the midpoint of the bar having width of 1. Hence the $y_{x}=y_{x}dx$. Does this help? Also I didn't understand the condition you mentioned: `both being normalized to probability one`. What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a binomial random variable with $n$ trials and Success
probability $p$ on each trial, then the number $X$ of heads observed
will become very nearly normal for large $n.$ The convergence to
normal is faster of $p = 1/2.$

Often one looks at $Z_n = \frac{X - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}},$ so that
$E(Z_n) = 0$ and $Var(Z_n) = 1.$ Then $Z_n$ 'converges in distribution'
to standard normal. Roughly speaking, that means 
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(Z_n \le c) = \Phi(c),$ where $\Phi$
denotes the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

For example, suppose $n = 100$ and $p = 1/2$ and let $X$ be the
number of successes. Then the exact value of $P(X \le 40) = 0.0284,$ to
four places. This can be found by summing the terms of the binomial
distribution from $P(X = 0)$ up through $P(X = 40).$ In R statistical
software, the computation is as follows:

```
pbinom(40, 100, .5)
## 0.02844397
```

Because this binomial distribution is nearly normal we can compute this
as
$$P(X \le 40) = P(X \le 40.5) = P\left(\frac{X - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \le 
\frac{40.5 - 50}{5} = -1.9 \right) \approx \Phi(-1.9),$$

which can be evaluated as 0.0287, using printed normal tables or software.

```
pnorm(-1.9)
## 0.02871656
```

[Using 40.5 instead of 40 allows a better match between the discrete
binomial distribution and the continuous normal distribution. This is
sometimes called a 'continuity correction'.]

The plot below shows values of $\mathsf{Binom}(100,.25)$ with substantial
probability, along with the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50,\,\sigma=5).$ The relevant probability is to the left of the
vertical red line.

[image]

Also, if $n = 1000$ and $p = 1/4$ then $E(X) = 250$ and $SD(X) = 13.6931.$
If we seek $P(X \le 275)$ the exact value to four places is 0.9677,
and the value from a normal approximation is 0.9687. This illustrates
that the convergence of binomial to normal is usefu even if $p \ne 1/2,$
provided $n$ is sufficiently large. [Usually,
the normal approximation gives about two-place accuracy.]

```
pbinom(275, 1000, .25)
## 0.9677063
pnorm(275.5, 250, 13.6931)
## 0.9687162
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The binomial $\text{pdf}$ is

$$B_k=\binom nkp^kq^{n-k}$$

while the corresponding normal approximation would be

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}e^{-(k-np)^2/2npq}.$$

More precisely, we obtain the probability of the $k^{th}$ bin by integrating between half integers,

$$N_k=\int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}e^{-(k-np)^2/2npq}dt=\Phi\left(\frac{k+\frac12-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{k-\frac12-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right).$$

In the case of a fair coin,

$$B_k=\binom nk\frac1{2^n},$$

$$N_k=\Phi\left(\frac{2k-n+1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{2k-n-1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\approx\sqrt{\frac2{\pi n}}e^{-(2k-n)^2/2n}=\tilde N_k.$$

Comparing these curves seems barely tractable by analytical methods.

The plot below shows the discrepancies between the Binomial and Normal laws, either exact or approximated, for $n=100$.

[image]

Fortunately, the largest error seems to occur in the middle, where

$$B_{n/2}=\binom n{n/2}\frac1{2^n},$$
$$N_{n/2}=2\Phi\left(\frac1n\right).$$

Note that approximating the Binomial term by Stirling makes the two values equal, so that a better approximation is required.

From Wikipedia,

$$\binom n{n/2}\approx2^n\sqrt{{\frac 2{\pi n}}}\left(1-\frac{2c_n}n\right)$$ with $\frac19<c_n<\frac18$. Hence the maximum error decreases like $$\frac1n.$$